# Mandrill personalized message to recipients with same email

Tags: mandrill

In a NodeJs app I'm using Mandrill to send email reminders to people signed up to different kind of events. Every five minutes the app check for ready reminders and send these. The number or reminders can vary from zero to many at every check.

But here comes the problems:

If for example 3 ready reminder are found at a certain check, and two of these have the same recipient (same email), but different `merge_vars` because they are about different events. When sent only one (the first found?) set of `merge_vars` will be used to **both** of these recipients.

So, how do I keep unique `merge_vars` even to multiple recipients with the same email? I guess i could split duplicated email adresses into several different calls. But I would really like to do one call, and send one array of recipients. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you ever have a solution for this (besides multiple requests) ?

Comment: It was a while since I worked on this now... but I think i did a loop sending individual mails instead of sending a batch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time, Mandrill uses email addresses as a unique identifier for merge vars in API calls, so it's only possible to provide one set of merge values for an email address, even if you've specified that address multiple times in the `messages.to` parameter. If you have multiple unique emails to send to the same recipient, that should be handled in separate API calls at this time.

Comment: I have almost same problem. In some of my cases same recipients will get multiple emails but different merge_vars. So I must need to use two different API calls? There are no way to do this in single API call? (I was pulling my hair off before seeing this answer)

Comment: @rafi +1 also have the same issue. Is there a roadmap issue for this, or is this never going to be solved?

Comment: @AndyHayden nope, mandrill haven't solved this issue. So for now, I am using separate API calls for same email addresses.

Comment: +1, running into this as well. Thanks for the answer, but now I'm making 100+ individual api calls instead of just one...

Comment: +1 Maybe Mandrill can solve this by allowing us to provide a unique identifier to tie the pairs of recipient and merge_vars together?

Comment: +1 This troubles me also. I am trying to bcc my self in some important emails. I want to send those with one call but I can't get my bcc mail to handle different merge_vars.. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier workaround than multiple API calls, and confirmed it works. Append a unique identifier to each email address using the "+" symbol. Then multiple emails to the same person will technically be to different email addresses, so Mandrill's merge fields will work correctly. e.g.

```
example+event1@example.com
example+event2@example.com
example+event3@example.com
```

All three of these will be delivered with the correct merging to example@example.com, and the recipient can even filter by the exact addresses if they wish when searching for the messages later.

(I am having the same issue now in 2019, so assume the original problem hasn't been fixed on Mandrill.)

Edit: The above method will not work with @yahoo.com recipients, as they don't support sub-addressing. The emails will bounce as if the address doesn't exist. (I consider that a problem with Yahoo, not the answer, since it's standard. But anyway, if you are emailing a group with a lot of yahoos... erm, yahoo.com emails I mean, then this method won't help.)